# Keyword global:: when adding reference

Tags: c#, .net, reference, resharper

I've encountered a strange phenomenon today as I added a reference of a project to another project and trying to use an interface of the referenced assembly:

**Situation:**

- The class `MySampleApplication` is in the project `MyApplication`.
- The interface `IMySampleApplication` is in the referenced project `MyApplication.Interfaces`.

When I do this:

```
public class MySampleApplication : IMySampleApplication
```

Resharper adds the following using:

```
using global::MyApplication.Interfaces;
```

**Question:**

> Why is it adding the `global::` prefix and how can I avoid this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's not causing the application to work improperly but I've never seen it before and I want to understand what it does since I've never had to add it when adding references before

Comment: @roryap, why the aggression? SO isn't just a place for "my code's broke; help" questions; questions such as this, enquiring as to why code needs to be written in an unusual way to get it to work are equally valid.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll have two occurrences of `MyApplication` somewhere in your code, eg you'll likely have a class called `MyApplication` in your local project as well as the namespace in the MyApplication project.

The local `MyApplication` will take precedence over the namespace in your MyApplication project, so `MyApplication.Interfaces` will not be found. To get around this, the special alias `global::` can be used to tell the compiler that in this case `MyApplication` refers to a base namespace and so `MyApplication.Interfaces` can then be correctly identified.

As to how to avoid it, that's easy to say, but it may be harder to achieve: rename one of them to remove the name conflict...

Comment: thank you for the clarification, this was indeed the case :-)

Answer (score 2):

You probably have another entity called MyApplication in your project which is hiding the namespace.

See: ["How to: Use the Global Namespace Alias (C# Programming Guide)"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3ay4x3d.aspx)